# How can I reduce the strain on my ports where large heavy adapters must plug in?

Tags: port, dvi, mac-mini, mini-displayport, mini-dvi

On the back of my Mac Mini are 2 video output ports. I am using both of them. They are the [Mini DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort) and the [Mini DVI port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI).

I have 2 rather large adapters that convert from the newer style port to standard [DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface).

Now, the weight of these seem to be an awful lot on these ports. They seem to both be plugged in at sharp angles (well at least as sharp as the port will allow).

Now I've thought of a few fixes

- Get extensions (Mini DVI female to male) to go from the back of the Mac Mini, and then on the floor have the adapter. Downsides to this are more cost, and more length of cable being run.
- Use a cable tie through the exhaust vent grill and attach it so the cable is being pulled level as it leaves the port. Downsides are it may block the cooling, and it will not be able to be removed easily.

Is there any other way to solve this problem? I'd hate to break a port, as I'm sure they'd be soldered straight to a PCB.

Comment: Extensions sound like the way to go IMO

Comment: There is no port like a screwed in serial port ... you could hang the entire box by that thing(!)  :)

Comment: @Idigas What about the old parallel ports? They were 10cm wide and my old Packard Bell used large clips to hold it in!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend extensions also.  However, if cost is an issue you could tape a stack of pennies together to prop up the connector.

Comment: And it would be easy to figure out the total cost of the fix!

Comment: @Jared Haha, made me smile. +1